# ANTLR: token to text in rewrite rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm building an AST using ANTLR. I want to write a production that matches this string:

```
${identifier}
```

In my grammar file I have:

```
reference
  : DOLLAR LBRACE IDENT RBRACE -> ^(NODE_VAR_REFERENCE IDENT)
;
```

This works fine. I'm using my own adaptor to emit tree nodes.
The rewrite rule used creates for me two nodes: one for `NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` and one for `IDENT`.

What I want to do is create only one node (for the `NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` token), and this node must have the `IDENT` token in its "token" field.

Is this possible using a rewrite rule? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to let `IDENT` be the token of the node `NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` would mean there isn't any `NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` at all. A token consists of a type (`NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` or `IDENT`) and some text this token matched. To let a tree node's token become `IDENT` would mean both the type *and* text would be that of `IDENT` (losing the `NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` token, or type).

What you probably mean is to have single node with type `NODE_VAR_REFERENCE` and the text of `IDENT`, in which case you could do something like  this:

```
reference
 : DOLLAR LBRACE IDENT RBRACE -> NODE_VAR_REFERENCE[$IDENT.text]
 ;
```